# return doesn't work, console.log works

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return-value, addition

I'm trying to add array numbers:

```
function addNumbers(arr){
  var x = 0 ;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   x = x + arr[i];
  }
  console.log(x)
  // console.log prints 28
  // return prints undefined
}
var sum = addNumbers([2, 10, 4, 8, 4]);
```

I'm trying to have this function return 28. So far it only works with `console.log()`. What am I missing here?

Comment: `return x;`? What does that give you?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return x;` here.

```
function addNumbers(arr){
  var x = 0 ;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   x = x + arr[i];
  }
  console.log(x)
  // console.log prints 28
  // return prints undefined
  return x;
}
var sum = addNumbers([2, 10, 4, 8, 4]);
```

Working demo is in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3zxLw3s/)